# Calling a recursive function that includes a promise in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, recursion, promise, cheerio

I'm trying to build a json tree by parsing xml files.  These files may contain references to other xml files.  All files I'd like to parse have names like `toc\d.js`.  The outputted tree should have the form:

```
{
  name: 'name of element', 
  url: 'xml_referenced.xml',
  children: [
  {
     name: '.....',
     url: '.....',
     children: [...]
   }
}
```

The xml that should produce this may look like the following (toc.xml)

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><data  src=\"toc.js\"  name=\"Using and Customizing the Application\" url=\"DA_UsingAndCustomizing.htm\"><item name=\"Adapted user interface\" url=\"DA_AdaptedUserInterface.htm\" /><item name=\"Show or hide the windows\" url=\"3402556939.htm\" /><book  src=\"toc2.js\"  name=\"Work with layouts\" url=\"9007202657330059.htm\" /><book  src=\"toc3.js\"  name=\"Adjust table views\" url=\"3402653835.htm\" /><item name=\"Use the keyboard to access the ribbon\" url=\"9007202657380875.htm\" /><item name=\"Keyboard shortcuts\" url=\"27021601196225675.htm\" /><item name=\"Lock or unlock the Data Analysis session\" url=\"27021601166795787.htm\" /><item name=\"Reset all user settings\" url=\"3402736267.htm\" /><item name=\"Find status information\" url=\"9007203112007179.htm\" /><item name=\"Navigation pane\" url=\"18014401941480331.htm\" /><item name=\"PDF Viewer\" url=\"OL_PDFViewer.htm\" /><item name=\"Review mode\" url=\"DA_ReviewMode.htm\" /><item name=\"Customize reports and results\" url=\"DA_CustomizeReportsAndResults.htm\" /><book  src=\"toc4.js\"  name=\"Interfaces\" url=\"DA_Interfaces.htm\" /></data>"
```

As you can see, it contains elements that reference further 'toc' files (will be converted to xml, as they are stored as js):

```
<book  src=\"toc2.js\"  name=\"Work with layouts\" url=\"9007202657330059.htm\" />
```

The function I use to parse is the following:

```
var loadedPaths = []
var buildTOC = function(xml, srcPath){
    const parseToc = function(toc){
        var obj = {}
        var children
        if (toc.children.length){
            children = toc.children   // THESE ITEMS ARE INCLUDED IN THE RESULT
        }
        else {
            children = []
        }
        var path = toc.attribs.src
        if (path && loadedPaths.indexOf(path)<0){
            loadedPaths.push(path)
            lib.getXml(srcPath + '/' + toc.attribs.src).then(x => { // RETURNS XML
                children = lib.buildTOC(x, srcPath)  // THESE ITEMS ARE NOT INCLUDED 

            })
        }
        else {
            obj.url = toc.attribs.url
            obj.name = toc.attribs.name
            obj.children = children.map(x => {return parseToc(x)})
        }
        return obj
    }
    var $ = this.buildDom(xml, {xmlMode: true})  // RETURNS A CHEERIO DOM
    console.log([parseToc($('data')[0])])
    return [parseToc($('data')[0])]


}
```

The result only includes the `<item>` and `<book>` elements in the original toc.xml file.  What I'm expecting is for `<book>` elements to also include children, which are the children of the `<data>` tag within files like toc2.js, toc3.js, etc.

Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong here?  Thanks.

Comment: The code inside `then` is asynchronous. It will be executed only when getXml will resolve, which will happen long after the rest of your code has been executed.

Comment: You could mark your function as `async`, and then  -> `const x = await lib.getXml(srcPath + '/' + toc.attribs.src)`   should do it.   Of course this will then be a Promise, so call using another `await`, or `func().then()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would do this kind of stuff with promises:

```js
var buildTOC = function (xml, srcPath) {
  const parseToc = function (toc) {
    const children = ...; // create the children url list here

    const childrenToc =
      children.length === 0
        ? Promise.resolve([])
        : Promise.all(
            children.map(childUrl => load(childUrl))
          ).then(childXml => buildTOC(childXml));

    // here, load would be your lib.getXml function
    return childrenToc.then(childrenTocsList => ({
      url: toc.attribs.url,
      name: toc.attribs.name,
      children: childrenTocsList,
    }));
  };

  var $ = this.buildDom(xml, {xmlMode: true}); // RETURNS A CHEERIO DOM
  return parseToc($("data")[0]);
};

// Usage:
buildTOC(myXML, mySrcPath).then(result => console.log(result));
```

You just need to create the `children` list and the `load` function to fulfill your needs.

Comment: When I run this I get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: children.map(...).then is not a function`.  I defined children as `['toc2.js', 'toc3.js']`.  I replaced `load` with `lib.getXml(childUrl)`.  Is this what you had in mind?  I don't see how `children.map` can have a `then` method.

Comment: Don't forget to use the srcPath to create the children url. You can use it either when building the children list or inside the load method.